# Display data from same column in multiple columns without duplicating SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in SQL Server like this -

```
    
    Num   Alphabet
    1    A
    1    B
    2    C
    2    D
    2    E
    3    F
```

Can you help me make an SQL query that will display the data like this -

```
    
    Alpha1    Alpha2    Alpha3
    A         C         F
    B         D
              E
```

Comment: What is the logic behind it, in other form What is the relation between Alpha1, [A, B]  and Alpha2, [C, D, E],... are you missing more table details?

Comment: Relation is Column - "Num"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate the values before you pivot them.  Here is one method for getting the results you want:

```
select max(case when num = 1 then alphabet end) as alpha1,
       max(case when num = 2 then alphabet end) as alpha2,
       max(case when num = 3 then alphabet end) as alpha3       
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by num order by alphabet) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: What if new alphabet added ?

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh . . . A new number would require modifying the query.  I note that is not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a subquery and group by clause:

```
select max(case when num = 1 then Alphabet end) as alpha1,
       max(case when num = 2 then Alphabet end) as alph2,
       max(case when num = 3 then Alphabet end) as alph3
from (select *, row_number()
      over (partition by num order by alphabet) as output
      from tblTemp) temp
group by output;
```

Comment: It would be better to include the code directly as a text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this will take care of any number of alphabets in your column

A dynamic Pivot Query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[num]) 
            FROM [YourTable] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT num, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select num, Alphabet, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY num order by Alphabet asc) as uid
                from [YourTable]
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MIN(Alphabet)
                for [uid] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

print @query
```

Comment: Thanx, but it isn't the requirement at this time.